# I am getting an error "header is not defined" while tring to use CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i am a beginner and i was trying to make a real time chat application. I am using socket.io to establish a connection between two users.
On the backend i am using Node.js.
I got an error "No Access Control Origin Header" present. So I added the following headers to my code.

```
//Node server which will handle socket io connections
import fetch, {Headers} from 'node-fetch'
/* const fetch = require('node-fetch'); */
global.fetch = fetch
global.headers = fetch.Headers;

if (!globalThis.fetch) {
  globalThis.fetch = fetch
  globalThis.Headers = Headers
}

/* const fetch = require("node-fetch"); */

/* var header = new fetch.Headers(); */

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
/* /* let cors = require("cors"); */
let express = require('express')
let cors = require("cors");
var app = express()
app.use(cors());
```

But now i am getting the error headers is not defined. If anyone can guidein this regard, it would be great.

Comment: Becuase `header` is `undefined`. What is this `header` function supposed to do? You already use `cors`

Comment: i.e. remove all those lines that start `header(` ... the `cors` module handles CORS for you

Comment: Node.js isn't PHP. Also, if you're a beginner you shouldn't start with wanting to build the next Slack, start with actually getting a simple HTTP server up and running.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to look at here...

1. there's no definition of `header` by default and you're getting this error because of the same.
2. Since you're using the `cors` everything you want to handle, can be handled with cors.
3. incase if you still want to add the headers like that, then create a custom middleware, add these lines inside the middleware, and use it in the code with `app.use()`

something like this :

```
var headerSettings = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'example.com');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}

app.use(headerSettings);
```

Hope this answer helps you!!